# How to play audio from resource

Tags: .net, compact-framework, audio

I am trying to play audio from a resource using .NET Compact Framework. I added an audio file for the resource property in my application and am trying to use the below sample resource file reference code for...

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
    GetManifestResourceStream("blessedwav.wav"));
player.Play();
```

But this code doesn't play a WAV sound. How do I play the resource audio file using .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 7):

I got the solution. This code is working very well in .NET Compact Framework:

```
// Convert a byte array to a stream
using (var audioStream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.full_song_wav))
{
    using (var player = new SoundPlayer(audioStream))
    {
        player.Play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
//I added the file as a audio resource in my project
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.recycle);
player.Play();
```

I didn't try with .NET Compact Framework. But it is working for me in C#.

Comment: am try this code, but it's not working .Net CF, 
It's showing Error : The best overloaded method match for System.Media.SoundPlayer.SoundPlayer(string)' has some invalid arguments.  
anyway Thanks anuraj

Comment: Hmm, so I think .Net CF got only one overload which is using string as the argument. Then why don't you save the file to a Temp location and play it from there.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
Stream str = Properties.Resources.YourWaveSoundFile;
SoundPlayer plyr = new SoundPlayer(str);
plyr.Play();
```

Make sure you have `using System.Media` above your namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("nudgeSound", Resources.Culture);
System.IO.Stream s = Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("nudgeSound", Resources.Culture);
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(s);
player.Play();
```