# How to play WAV audio file from Resources?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, audio

How can I play a WAV audio file in from my project's Resources? My project is a Windows Forms application in C#.

Comment: [This is what you are looking for.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w5b27z4.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Stream str = Properties.Resources.mySoundFile;
RecordPlayer rp = new RecordPlayer();
rp.Open(new WaveReader(str));
rp.Play();
```

From *[How to play WAV audio file from resources in C#](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip137)*.

Answer (score 61):

Because `mySoundFile` is a `Stream`, you can take advantage of `SoundPlayer`'s overloaded constructor, which accepts a `Stream` object:

```
System.IO.Stream str = Properties.Resources.mySoundFile;
System.Media.SoundPlayer snd = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(str);
snd.Play();
```

[SoundPlayer Class Documentation (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx)

Comment: This will throw an exception in Windows CE because it won't automatically convert the resource from a byte[] to a stream. I found the following answer worked in that scenario. Leaving it here for others:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900707/how-to-play-audio-from-resource

Comment: We actually dont need to declare a separate Stream variable ;)

Comment: @TomeeNS: Of course, but it shows people the type of the resource and the overload of the `SoundPlayer` constructor that is used.

Comment: This Answer is better than the marked answer cause you don't need extra classes that might be outdated. As well the Writer did type the Namespaces as well.

Answer (score 53):

**a) OK, first add audio file (.wav) into project resource.**

1. Open "Solution Explorer" from menu toolbar ("VIEW") or simply press Ctrl+Alt+L.
2. Click on drop-down list of "Properties".
3. Then select "Resource.resx" and press enter.

[image: open project resource]

4. Now select "Audio" from the combobox list.

[image: add audio files to resource]

5. Then click on "Add Resource", choose audio files (.wav) and click "Open".

[image: browsing for audio files]

6. Select audio file(s) and change "Persistence" properties to "Embedded in .resx".

[image: embedding audio files to resource]

**b) Now, just write this code to play the audio.**

In this code I'm playing audio on form load event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Media; // at first you've to import this package to access SoundPlayer

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {
        public login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            playaudio(); // calling the function
        }

        private void playaudio() // defining the function
        {
            SoundPlayer audio = new SoundPlayer(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.Connect); // here WindowsFormsApplication1 is the namespace and Connect is the audio file name
            audio.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

That's it.
All done, now run the project (press f5) and enjoy your sound.
All the best. :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! The pictures helped a lot. Do you know if I can embed a font (like fontawesome) this way as well for use in my program?

Comment: When I add a wav file it adds a Resources2.Designer.cs which seems to be a duplicate of Resources.Designer.cs - thus giving me conflicts. This just started happening.Any ideas what could be happening? https://www.screencast.com/t/xAVpE5v6b0

Answer (score 2):

You need to be cautious about the garbage collector freeing up memory used by your sound while the sound is still playing.  While it rarely happens, when it does, you will just be playing some random memory.  There is a solution to this, complete with source code for achieving what you want here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680(VS.85).aspx

Scroll to the very bottom, in the "Community Content" section.

Answer (score 1):

Theses two lines can do it:

```
SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.solo);     
sound.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to add sounds into your project, you will do so by playing `.wav` file(s). Then you have to add the `.wav` file(s) like this.

```
using System.Media; //write this at the top of the code

SoundPlayer my_wave_file = new SoundPlayer("F:/SOund wave file/airplanefly.wav");
my_wave_file.PlaySync(); // PlaySync means that once sound start then no other activity if form will occur untill sound goes to finish
```

Remember that you have to write the path of the file with **forward slashes** (`/`) format, don't use **back slashes** (`\`) when giving a path to the file, else you will get an error.

Also note, if you want other things to happen while the sound is playing, you can change `my_wave_file.PlaySync();` with `my_wave_file.PlayAsync();`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do so as far as I know, list below:

1. **Use file path**

First put the file in the root folder of the project, then no matter you run the program under `Debug` or `Release` mode, the file can both be accessed for sure. Then use the class `SoundPlayer` to paly it.
But in this way, if you want to release the project to users, you need to copy the sound files with its folder hierarchies except hierarchies the folder "Release" under the "bin" directory.

```
var basePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = Path.Combine(basePath, @"./../../Reminder.wav");
player.Load();
player.Play();
```

2. **Use resource**

Follow below animate, add "Exsiting file" to the project.

[image]

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Reminder);
player.Play();
```

The strength of this way is:
Only the folder "Release" under the "bin" directory need to be copy when run the program.