# Playing Music from resources C#

Tags: c#, audio, resources

I want to play some background music inside the launcher for my new project. But I get an error.

```
private void playlooping()
{
    SoundPlayer.PlayLooping(system.Resources.Bgm);
}

//Bgm is the name of the song.
```

For some reason I get the error

> no overload for method 'PlayLooping' Takes 1 arguments

Comment: it basically means that you can't call `PlayLooping` with only one or any argument. Looking at the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbx06asw(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that `PlayLooping` doesn't take any arguments. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125698/how-to-play-wav-audio-file-from-resources) answer helps you out.

Comment: then how do i assign my music file to the playlooping. How do i tell it to play the file i want to

Comment: is your resource a path to the audio file or the audio file itself?

Comment: I added the audio file in my recourses so this path is to the audio file. not the original one if thats what you ment ?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, `PlayLooping does not take any arguments`. So you need to specify the sound you want to play somewhere else. This is done either by setting it via the `SoundPlayer`-Constructor like this:

```
// via string path
var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\somePath\someFile.wav");

// via stream
var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(musicStream);
```

So if your resource is a string you should be good to go with:

```
var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(system.Resources.Bgm);
```

Alternative is to set the string-path or stream after instantiating your `SoundPlayer` via the `Site`- or `Stream`-Properties of your `SoundPlayer` object:

```
var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer();

// via path
soundPlayer.Site = @"C:\path\test.wav";

// via stream
soundPlayer.Stream = someStream;
```

After setting this up correclty you should be good calling `PlayLooping`. So your final code should be looking like this (works for me in a test windows forms application, with the soundfile simply put in my debug folder):

```
var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer("test.wav");
soundPlayer.PlayLooping();
```

You can find the full documentation on the `SoundPlayer` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay i replace the  SoundPlayer.PlayLooping(system.Resources.Bgm); with the var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(system.Resources.Bgm); line. the good thing is the error is gone. the bad thing is. i still dont hear music when i launch the app

Comment: well you should still call `soundPlayer.PlayLooping()` : )

Comment: "soundplayer does not contain a definition for PLaylooping"??

Comment: private void PlayLooping()
        {
            SoundPlayer.Playlooping();
            var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Resources.Bgm);
        }

Comment: It should be like this: `var soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Resources.Bgm); soundPlayer.PlayLooping();`

Comment: I'm gonna assume that you should be looking a bit more into the core concepts of c# and object oriented programming, probably looking into a few tutorials.

Comment: Sorry but i still dont hear any music all errors are gone. And i need to do this for a school project so im stil learning the basics.

Comment: then you are probably not even calling your own "PlayLooping" method.

Comment: What do you mean with that ?

Comment: your `private void PlayLooping() { ... }`...you are probably not calling it from anywhere, so your code will never run. Sorry but I can't help you that much if you are seemingly lacking the needed basics.