# Sound in C#, where to put the audio files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have a simple C# program that I want to play a sound file with the name "m.wav". I add the audio file as "existing item" (in VS) and it's located in the same folder as the classes, program.cs etc (main folder/root).

Since it's located in the same directory as the rest of the files, I try to call the audio file with the following code;

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(); player.SoundLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\m.wav"; player.PlayLooping();
```

BUT the audio file can't be found. I have an example file that does exactly the same, but it actually works. What have I done wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be in the same directory as the EXE of this project?

Comment: The exe file runs from a `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` folder

Comment: Yes, because when you run your app inside Visual Studio debug session your code runs from the directory BIN\DEBUG. You should set the property of the file Copy To Output Directory to Copy Always

Comment: And for your end users, build an installer

Comment: Or add it to your resource file [How to Play WAV audio file from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125698/how-to-play-wav-audio-file-from-resources)

Comment: ... and use Path.Combine to safely format file paths.

Answer (score 1):

Left click on your file in the *Solution Explorer*, then look at the *Properties* window (hotkey <kbd>F4</kbd> by default).

There you look for a property named *Copy to Output Directory* and change its value to *Copy always* or *Copy if newer*.

This lets the file appear in your ouput directory (where your *.exe* file is) and your code should work.