# I am having trouble getting the sound to work in my asteroids game?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

So I have been coding a remake of the 1979 Atari game Asteroids, in C# Visual Studio 2019 Windows Forms app. The issue I am having is the sounds are not working correctly:

Here is where I implement the sound, for when a meteor hits the ship:

```cs
private void DetectShipToMeteorCollisions()
{
    if (!_ship.IsActive)
        return;

    for (int meteorIndex = 0; meteorIndex < _meteors.Count; meteorIndex++)
    {
        if (_meteors[meteorIndex].CollidesWithShip(_ship))
        {
            _meteors[meteorIndex].IsActive = false;
            GameManager.RaiseMeteorHit(_meteors[meteorIndex]);
            BlowUpShip();
        }
        SoundPlayer1 sound = new SoundPlayer1("bang_6.wav");
        sound.Play(); 
    }
}
```

// The "bang_6.wav" is imported into the Visual Studio project.

And here is the code for SoundPlayer1

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AsteroidsGdiApp.Core
{
    public class SoundPlayer1
    {
        private byte[] m_soundBytes;
        private string m_fileName;

        private enum Flags
        {
            SND_SYNC = 0x0000,  /* play synchronously (default) */
            SND_ASYNC = 0x0001,  /* play asynchronously */
            SND_NODEFAULT = 0x0002,  /* silence (!default) if sound not found */
            SND_MEMORY = 0x0004,  /* pszSound points to a memory file */
            SND_LOOP = 0x0008,  /* loop the sound until next sndPlaySound */
            SND_NOSTOP = 0x0010,  /* don't stop any currently playing sound */
            SND_NOWAIT = 0x00002000, /* don't wait if the driver is busy */
            SND_ALIAS = 0x00010000, /* name is a registry alias */
            SND_ALIAS_ID = 0x00110000, /* alias is a predefined ID */
            SND_FILENAME = 0x00020000, /* name is file name */
            SND_RESOURCE = 0x00040004  /* name is resource name or atom */
        }

        [DllImport("CoreDll.DLL", EntryPoint = "PlaySound", SetLastError = true)]
        private extern static int WCE_PlaySound(string szSound, IntPtr hMod, int flags);

        [DllImport("CoreDll.DLL", EntryPoint = "PlaySound", SetLastError = true)]
        private extern static int WCE_PlaySoundBytes(byte[] szSound, IntPtr hMod, int flags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct the Sound object to play sound data from the specified file.
        /// </summary>
        public SoundPlayer1(string fileName)
        {
            m_fileName = fileName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct the Sound object to play sound data from the specified stream.
        /// </summary>
        public SoundPlayer1(Stream stream)
        {
            // read the data from the stream
            m_soundBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(m_soundBytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Play the sound
        /// </summary>
        public void Play()
        {
            // if a file name has been registered, call WCE_PlaySound,
            //  otherwise call WCE_PlaySoundBytes
            if (m_fileName != null)
                WCE_PlaySound(m_fileName, IntPtr.Zero, (int)(Flags.SND_ASYNC | Flags.SND_FILENAME));
            else
                WCE_PlaySoundBytes(m_soundBytes, IntPtr.Zero, (int)(Flags.SND_ASYNC | Flags.SND_MEMORY));
        }

        public static void PlayEmbeddedSound(Assembly assembly, string resourceName)
        {
            SoundPlayer1 sound = new SoundPlayer1(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName));
            sound.Play();
        }

        public static void PlayFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            SoundPlayer1 sound = new SoundPlayer1(filePath);
            sound.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to compile once the sound is inserted produces this error:

I wonder why this might be? Thanks very much.

[image]

So upon fixing the error, I am  attempting to add a sound effect for when a bullet is fired. But for some reason it is not detecting this wav file when it has been imported into the project the same way.

I wonder why it is not finding this wav file.

Here is is, imported to the project. Thanks.

[image]

```cs
private void DetectBulletCollisions()
{

    for(int meteorIndex = 0; meteorIndex < _meteors.Count; meteorIndex++)
    {
        for (int bulletIndex = 0; bulletIndex < _photons.Length; bulletIndex++)
            
        {
            //TODO get rid of event drive desing here
            _meteors[meteorIndex].TestIfShot(_photons[bulletIndex]);
            System.IO.Stream str = Properties.Resources.mySoundFile;
            System.Media.SoundPlayer snd = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("gunshot.wav");
            snd.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception of gunshot.wav
[image]

Here the file is in same directory. So fact that Visual Studio is not seeing it is bizarre. It's imported in the visual studio project as well, thanks.

[image]

Comment: You say it's a windows forms app but coredll is for mobile applications I do believe.

Comment: Oh. What is the equivalent for Windows Forms? Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125698/how-to-play-wav-audio-file-from-resources

Comment: Oh that worked thanks! but now I am trying add a gun sound effect for when a bullet is fired. But for some reason, it's not seeing the wav file even though it's also been imported into the visual studio project:

Comment: Please see the added description for more details. Thanks.

Comment: is gunshot.wav in the same directory as the first sound file that worked? (bang_6.wav)?

Comment: Yes, that;s what makes it so strange?

Comment: What exception message did you get? Please post it.

Comment: Just did, added to the description. Thanks.