# Can't play a sound located in my references folder

Tags: c#

I know it's simple, but this is driving me crazy. I have loaded my wave file into my application resource/references file location. All I want to do is play this wave file for 5 seconds. I've searched high and low throughout the internet and no one has a simple solution. Am I not looking hard enough or is it more complex than it seems?
Here's a sample of my code:

```
if (attempts == win)
{
    label1.Text = "Great job!";
    level += 1;
    i = 0;
    attempts = "";
    win = "";
    cheaterLabel.Text = "";
}
```

I am working with Visual Studio 2008. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900707/how-to-play-audio-from-resource

Comment: This bit of code is not about sounds. . . I mean... not at all

Comment: Where is the sound? I seeeee... a label..a number..another number(PROBABLY AN INT), two strings and another label.

Answer (score 0):

The example is from this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18.aspx).

Well it's even easier than you think.

```
if (attempts == win)
{
playSimpleSound();
label1.Text = "Great job!";
level += 1;
i = 0;
attempts = "";
win = "";
cheaterLabel.Text = "";
}

 private void playSimpleSound()
{
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\SomeFile\someSound.wav");
simpleSound.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you have your file in your Application Resources you should be able to do something like this using SoundPlayer. I added the file by going to Project --> Properties --> Resources.

```
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.chord); \\Change to what ever the name of your resource is
sp.Play();
```