# Loading sounds from resources rather than a path?

Tags: c#, audio, resources

I want my sounds to be embedded in a folder called 'Sounds' in resources, but I tried things like [How to play audio from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900707/how-to-play-audio-from-resource) 'assembly'-streams and other things I found on Google, but no dice.

One of my methods works like this:

```
        foreach (string str in names)
        {
            try
            {
                SoundPlayer thisSound = new SoundPlayer(str + ".wav");
                thisSound.PlaySync();
            }
        ...
```

So the user puts in a name, it plays a sound corresponding the names. So for every name, I have a soundfile. This works fine with a path, but how do I do it if I want to play names through embedded sound-files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link you provided has answers that should work. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Properties.Resources. shows no sound files whatsoever. Do I have to add them in a special way or change their properties? They're just .wav files.

Comment: You should add your wav files as embedded resource. and use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11361355/2530848 It should work

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm stuck already at 'ResourceManager'. Mine has no GetStream. Maybe I'm using the wrong ResourceManager?

Comment: Post your attempt please. It is hard to guess and also easy to get wrong

Comment: Just tried adding it in the constructor and before the constructor as well. Wrote;
System.Resources.ResourceManager.

Comment: Right click your project > properties > resources > add your .wav files here // Properties.Resources.myWavfile will work

Comment: `MyProjectNamespace.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(...` not `System.Resources.ResourceManager.`

Comment: I took the easy way out and used Jim's suggestion. 
I added the resources in a wrong way. All good for now.